# Is there a way to configure the data protection provider for cookies in dotnet core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Locally cookies are created fine but after I deploy to my hosting environment no cookies are created because I have to persist data protection keys to the file system since user profile cannot be loaded in shared hosting environment. I changed the code locally to use the same mechanism to verify cookies are no longer created as this took me a while to track down. If there a way to configure the data protection provider for cookie creation? I have valid certs.

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        //needed for winhost as we cannot get user profiles from IIS there
        if (_env.IsProduction()) {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2($"{_env.ContentRootPath}\\App_Data\\nameofcert.pfx", "asdfasdf", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
             services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($"{_env.ContentRootPath}\\App_Data"))
            
                .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificate);
        } else {
            var devCertificate = new X509Certificate2($"{_env.ContentRootPath}\\App_Data\\cert.pfx", "wasdfasdfas", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($"{_env.ContentRootPath}\\App_Data"))
                
                .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(devCertificate);
        }
```

Comment: Does the file is generated under that specific folder on your server?

Comment: Locally key-1ba8c8b5-48b0-4106-9f56-df2e5b5f4d25.xml is generated under App_Data but I just noticed that it is not getting generated on the server. However, when using a dir as the key store the cookies are not generated locally either.

Comment: I verified that after deployment I am creating a key.xml file, encrypted with a valid certificate, in a directory on the server but I still see no cookies being created.

Comment: It's working now. It had nothing to do with the protect keys stuff it was my own error and an oversight on my part. Thanks.